# How to get last element of document in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection("todolist").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
console.log(querySnapshot[querySnapshot.length -1])})
```

**This results in undefined. How do i get the last element of a document?**

Answer (score 3):

If you're only interested in the last document, consider ordering the query, and requesting only one document, so save on the bandwidth and cost. Say you have a field named `timestamp`, you can get the latest one (and only that one) with:

```
db.collection("todolist")
  .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
  .limit(1)
  .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0])
  })
```

Since you now only requested one document, you can use `docs[0]` to get at it.

Answer (score 1):

`querySnapshot` isn't an array, so you can simply index into it.  It's a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot) object, and I strongly suggest you familiarize yourself with that API documentation.  You can see that it has a [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot.md#querysnapshotdocs) property, which *is* an array.

```
querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length-1]
```

or

```
querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.size-1]
```